# S3FS not reliably mounted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I have AWS instances using Amazon AMI Linux. I've made custom disk images with S3FS installed, that are launched by load balancer automatically. In the S3 bucket all the instances have shared images.

In /etc/fstab there is one line added

```
s3fs#mybucket:/images /var/app/current/images fuse uid=500,gid=500,allow_other,use_cache=/tmp/cache 0 0
```

The problem is, that whenever EC2 instance is started from this custom AMI, there is ~50% probability that S3 bucket will not be mounted correctly and the `Transport endpoint is not connected` is shown when df -h. How to make mounting of S3 bucket more reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `_netdev` to the options field.